# Pushing div down and append divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am new to jQuery.
I am trying to hide the div I clicked and then push down 4 divs adjacent to it  using animate. After this I want to append the another 4 divs in the space after the clicked div.

I have tried this

Here is my code

```
 (function () {
     $('#ccc').on('click', '.box', function () {
         var i = 0;
         $(this).fadeOut().nextAll().slice(0, 4).animate({
             top: '100px'
         }, function () {
             i++;
             if (i == 4) {
                 $(this).after('<div class="lt box"></div><div class="rt box"></div><div class="lt box"></div><div class="rt box"></div>');
             }
         });

     });

 })();
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ue7Gp/2/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It took some time, but try out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ue7Gp/8/).  Let me know if this is not the desired functionality.  Hope it helps.  The main problem with the original you posted was that the top: 100px style was being kept, which was causing that gap.

UPDATE:  I adjusted the javascript so only call the animation callback once so you could get rid of your counter.

EDIT 2:  I updated the fiddle and code below to reflect your request that the clicked box was not being removed.  I hope this helps

```
  (function () {
     $('#ccc').on('click', '.box', function (e) {
         var i = 0;
         $(e.currentTarget).fadeOut();
         $(e.currentTarget).nextAll().stop().animate({
            "top": "220px"
         }).promise().done( function () {
                 $(e.currentTarget).after('<div class="lt box"></div>
                 <div class="rt box"></div><div class="lt box"></div>
                 <div class="rt box"></div>').remove();
             $(".box").removeAttr("style");  
         });

     });

 })();



.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
     margin:5px;
}

#ccc {
    width:220px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. but clicked div is not hiding

Comment: I updated the code and the fiddle to reflect your request to remove the box when clicked.  If you want to keep all clicked boxes hidden instead of removing it, let me know and I can show you how to do that.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working for you for as much as I understand of your question. It should be enough to get you on the right track! The left and right floats aren't ideal IMO. Hope it helps!

Updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ue7Gp/3/

JS:

```
$('#ccc').on('click', '.box', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("lt")){
            var startwith = "lt";
            var endwith = "rt";
        } else {
            var startwith = "rt";
            var endwith = "lt";
        }
        for (x=0; x<2; x++){
            $(this).parent().prepend($('<div class="' + startwith + ' box"></div><div class="' + endwith + ' box">').hide().fadeIn("slow"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That was very helpful of you,But I want to animate the div push down and the divs in the center is overlapping when clicking